# setInterval triggering faster than set

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval

I am trying to build a dinosaur running game in React much like  [google chrome's](https://www.chromedinosaurgame.com/).

My idea is that I will run a function at the exact moment the object is suppose to hit the dinosaur, around 3 seconds

```
  function check4Death() {
        if (playerClass !== '') {
          console.log('safe')
        }
        else {
          console.log('nope')
          clearInterval()
        }
         }
    setInterval(check4Death, 3000)
```

This function checks to see if the player is currently in the air

As my method of jumping is adding and then removing a class from my playerClass object

```
  function Jump() {
    setPlayerClass('jump')
    setTimeout(() => {
      setPlayerClass('')
    }, 500);
  }
```

Instead of the function telling me either `safe` or `nope` every three seconds, I get this [image]

I am very confused as to why this is happening, I have a link to my full code [here](https://github.com/Imstupidpleasehelp/dinosaurGame/blob/main/src/jumpgame.js)

Comment: you're setting up a new interval on EACH RENDER, so of course you get loads of handlers. This needs to be inside a `useEffect` call that calls `clearInterval` in the returned function.

Comment: in general there are a lot of subtleties in using intervals with Hooks - there are lots of SO questions on this already if you search. It's probably worth using a pre-built hook such as [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-useinterval)

Comment: And [this](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/) Dan Abramov blog post, linked to in the above documentation, is an excellent explanation of some of these subtleties.

Comment: It appears I do not understand setInterval like I thought, thank you Robin Zigmond. It is now working as intended.

Comment: `setInterval()` returns a token. In order to clear that particular interval, you need to pass that token to `clearInterval()`.